# H2 not failing when inserting NULL into NOT NULL column

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

I use `H2`'s `mysql` mode in my spring boot project and everything works fine except that the H2 won't fail when I insert null value into a not null column. My datasourse url: `jdbc:h2:mem:test;mode=mysql;db_close_on_exit=false`. Is it a bug or something I missing?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_table` (
  `test_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `not_null_column` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

@Test
@Sql(statements = "INSERT INTO `test_table` (`test_id`, `not_null_column`) values ('1', null)")
public void testShouldFail() throws Exception { // would not fail!
}
```

**EDIT** If I use my own config as below, it works but without the `mysql` mode

```
@Configuration
public class H2Config {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're missing, but I know what we are missing. We are missing [mcve].

Comment: @xenteros I supplemented the example

Comment: where is your entity class?

Comment: @xenteros I just test the `h2`'s `non-null` constraint so it's no need to add entities here.